# How to show a web page as a tab view like toggle device toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to view a web page that looks like the toggle device toolbar. Using the JavaScript.

[image]

This is a youtube example. Is there any way to show the web page like every time just the tab/mobile view?

Comment: do you want the size widgets or just a site that is centered with a maximum width like mobile?

Comment: Actual I have an existing web site. Now I want to show the website with that mobile view

Comment: that doesn't answer the question. it's unclear what you intend to do. do you wish to make your site fit on mobile devices and desktop devices with varying widths, or do you wish to make your site always a mobile width?

Answer (score 0):

You can load different stylesheets based on the screen width. With these stylesheets, you can show the webpage however you like it for mobile devices (typically 600px in width and under).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/layout.css" media="(min-width: 600px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/mobile.css" media="(max-width: 599px)">
```

Comment: Actual I have an existing web site. Now I want to show the website with that mobile view.